# WiX Error LGHT0130 In InstallScopeDlg when modifying Wix_Advanced UI

Tags: wix, linker-errors

I am using WiX 3.6.
I am using the WIX_Advanced user interface and I want to replace the InstallScopeDlg with my own version (called InstallScopeDlgDsktp) which includes a checkbox for adding a Desktop shortcut.

When I do this, I take all the references to the old InstallScopeDlg in the WixUI_Advanced.wxs file, and override them in my main file to instead reference my custom InstallScopeDlgDsktp module.

However, when I try compiling, I get an error which seems to indicate there is a clash with a RadioButton table which means both my InstallScopeDlgDsktp and the original InstallScopeDlg must be adding a RadioButton based on the same property (WixAppFolder).

```
light Cryptobot.wixobj InstallScopeDlgDsktp.wixobj -ext WixUIExtension -out Cryptobot.msi
Microsoft (R) Windows Installer Xml Linker version 3.6.2221.0

<snip>wixlib\InstallScopeDlg.wxs(24): error LGHT0130 : 
The primary key 'WixAppFolder/1' is duplicated in table 'RadioButton'.  Please remove one of the entries or rename a part of the primary key to avoid the collision.
```

I can't seem to get around this.  My question is, why is it even linking in the original InstallScopeDlg module when I am not even referencing it any more?  How do I stop the original InstallScopeDlg from adding the RadioButton?

Code provided for reference:
Main WXS file (UI stuff is at the bottom - can see I replaced all instances of InstallScopeDlg with InstallScopeDlgDsktp):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">

   <!-- Defines -->
   <?define ProductName="Cryptobot" ?>
   <?define ProductVersion="1.1.1" ?>

   <Product Name="$(var.ProductName) $(var.ProductVersion)" Id="*"  
      UpgradeCode="MY-UPGRADE-GUID"  
      Language="1033" Codepage="1252" Version="$(var.ProductVersion)" Manufacturer="Crafted From Code">
  <!-- The Package GUID must be changed EVERY timeyou build a new .msi.  The asterisk makes this happen automatically. -->
  <Package Id="*" Keywords="Installer" 
     Description="$(var.ProductName) $(var.ProductVersion) Setup"
     Manufacturer="Crafted From Code"
     InstallerVersion="200" Languages="1033" Compressed="yes" />

  <Media Id="1" Cabinet="$(var.ProductName).cab" EmbedCab="yes" />

  <!-- Components to install -->
  <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
     <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="CraftedFromCode" Name="Crafted From Code">
           <Directory Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Name="$(var.ProductName)">
              <Component Id="MainExecutable" Guid="MY-GUID">
                 <File Id="CryptobotEXE" Name="Cryptobot.exe" Source="..\Cryptobot\bin\Release\Cryptobot.exe" KeyPath="yes">
                    <Shortcut Id="CryptobotProgramMenuShortcut" Directory="ProgramMenuDir" 
                       Name="$(var.ProductName)" Icon="Cryptobot.ico" IconIndex="0" Advertise="yes" />
                    <Shortcut Id="CryptobotDesktopShortcut" Directory="DesktopFolder" 
                       Name="$(var.ProductName)" Icon="Cryptobot.ico" IconIndex="0" Advertise="yes" />
                 </File>
                 <RemoveFolder Id="APPLICATIONFOLDER" On="uninstall" />
              </Component>
           </Directory>
        </Directory>
     </Directory>

     <!-- Start Menu Shortcut(s) -->
     <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder" Name="Programs">
        <Directory Id="ProgramMenuDir" Name="$(var.ProductName)">
           <Component Id="ProgramMenuShortcut" Guid="MY-GUID" >
              <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Crafted From Code\Cryptobot" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes" />
              <RemoveFolder Id="ProgramMenuDir" On="uninstall" />
           </Component>
        </Directory>
     </Directory>

     <!-- Desktop Shortcut -->
     <Directory Id="DesktopFolder">
        <Component Id="DesktopShortcut" Guid="MY-GUID">
           <Condition>INSTALLDESKTOPSHORTCUT</Condition>
           <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Crafted From Code\Cryptobot" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes" />
        </Component>
     </Directory>

  </Directory> <!-- End of TARGETDIR root directory -->


  <Icon Id="Cryptobot.ico" SourceFile="Cryptobot.ico" />

  <Feature Id="Complete" Level="1" Title="$(var.ProductName)" 
     Description="The complete package." Display="expand" 
     ConfigurableDirectory="APPLICATIONFOLDER">
     <ComponentRef Id="MainExecutable" />
     <ComponentRef Id="ProgramMenuShortcut" />
     <ComponentRef Id="DesktopShortcut" />
  </Feature>

  <!-- Upgrade rules: If a newer version is found, don't allow installation of an older version (downgrading).
  Otherwise, if an older version is already installed, remove it before installing the current version -->
  <Upgrade Id="MY-UPGRADE-GUID">
     <UpgradeVersion OnlyDetect="yes" Property="NEWERPRODUCTFOUND" Minimum="$(var.ProductVersion)" IncludeMinimum="no" />
     <!-- Setting IncludeMaximum to yes generates a linker warning, but it means that we can install over the
     same version without necessarily having to change the version number. -->
     <UpgradeVersion OnlyDetect="no" Property="PREVIOUSVERSIONINSTALLED" Minimum="1.0.0" IncludeMinimum="yes" Maximum="$(var.ProductVersion)" IncludeMaximum="yes" />
  </Upgrade>

  <CustomAction Id='PreventDowngrading' Error='A newer version of $(var.ProductName) is already installed.' />

  <InstallExecuteSequence>
     <Custom Action='PreventDowngrading' After='FindRelatedProducts'>NEWERPRODUCTFOUND</Custom>
     <RemoveExistingProducts After="InstallFinalize" />
  </InstallExecuteSequence>

  <InstallUISequence>
     <Custom Action='PreventDowngrading' After='FindRelatedProducts'>NEWERPRODUCTFOUND</Custom>
  </InstallUISequence>

  <!-- User Interface: Use the Advanced WiX interface, which will allow 1-click installation or 
  per user/per machine installation & install directory to be specified -->
  <UIRef Id="WixUI_Advanced" />
  <UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText" />
  <Property Id="ApplicationFolderName" Value="Crafted From Code\Cryptobot" />  
  <Property Id="WixAppFolder" Value="WixPerUserFolder" /> <!-- Defaults to install for all users -->
  <Property Id="INSTALLDESKTOPSHORTCUT" Value="1" /> <!-- Support for a desktop shortcut -->

  <!-- Add a checkbox to launch the application when the installer exits -->
  <Property Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOXTEXT" Value="Launch $(var.ProductName) when setup exits." />
  <!-- Have it ticked by default -->
  <Property Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX" Value="1" />
  <CustomAction Id="StartAppOnExit" FileKey="CryptobotEXE" ExeCommand="" Execute="immediate" Impersonate="yes" Return="asyncNoWait" />


  <UI Id="WixUI_AdvancedCrypto">
     <UIRef Id="WixUI_Advanced" />

     <DialogRef Id="InstallScopeDlgDsktp" />

     <Publish Dialog="AdvancedWelcomeEulaDlg" Control="Advanced" Event="NewDialog" Value="InstallScopeDlgDsktp" Order="1">!(wix.WixUISupportPerMachine) AND !(wix.WixUISupportPerUser)</Publish>

     <Publish Dialog="InstallScopeDlgDsktp" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="AdvancedWelcomeEulaDlg">1</Publish>
     <!-- override default WixAppFolder of WixPerMachineFolder as standard user won't be shown the radio group to set WixAppFolder -->
     <Publish Dialog="InstallScopeDlgDsktp" Control="Next" Property="WixAppFolder" Value="WixPerUserFolder" Order="1">!(wix.WixUISupportPerUser) AND NOT Privileged</Publish>
     <Publish Dialog="InstallScopeDlgDsktp" Control="Next" Property="ALLUSERS" Value="{}" Order="2">WixAppFolder = "WixPerUserFolder"</Publish>
     <Publish Dialog="InstallScopeDlgDsktp" Control="Next" Property="ALLUSERS" Value="1" Order="3">WixAppFolder = "WixPerMachineFolder"</Publish>
     <Publish Dialog="InstallScopeDlgDsktp" Control="Next" Property="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Value="[WixPerUserFolder]" Order="4">WixAppFolder = "WixPerUserFolder"</Publish>
     <Publish Dialog="InstallScopeDlgDsktp" Control="Next" Property="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Value="[WixPerMachineFolder]" Order="5">WixAppFolder = "WixPerMachineFolder"</Publish>
     <Publish Dialog="InstallScopeDlgDsktp" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="FeaturesDlg" Order="6">WixAppFolder = "WixPerUserFolder"</Publish>
     <Publish Dialog="InstallScopeDlgDsktp" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="InstallDirDlg" Order="7">WixAppFolder = "WixPerMachineFolder"</Publish>

     <Publish Dialog="FeaturesDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="InstallScopeDlgDsktp">NOT Installed AND WixAppFolder = "WixPerUserFolder"</Publish>
     <Publish Dialog="InstallDirDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="InstallScopeDlgDsktp">!(wix.WixUISupportPerUser)</Publish>         


     <!-- Add the check box for launching the app on completion -->
     <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Order="1" Event="DoAction" Value="StartAppOnExit">WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX = 1 AND NOT Installed</Publish>
  </UI>


</Product>
</Wix>
```

And the InstallScopeDlgDsktp file is just a copy of InstallScopeDlg with a checkbox added and the name changed:

```
<snip>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <UI>
            <Dialog Id="InstallScopeDlgDsktp" Width="370" Height="270" Title="!(loc.InstallScopeDlg_Title)" KeepModeless="yes">
                <Control Id="BannerBitmap" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="370" Height="44" TabSkip="no" Text="!(loc.InstallScopeDlgBannerBitmap)" />
                <Control Id="BannerLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="44" Width="370" Height="0" />
                <Control Id="BottomLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="234" Width="370" Height="0" />
                <Control Id="Description" Type="Text" X="25" Y="23" Width="280" Height="20" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.InstallScopeDlgDescription)" />
                <Control Id="Title" Type="Text" X="15" Y="6" Width="200" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.InstallScopeDlgTitle)" />
                <Control Id="BothScopes" Type="RadioButtonGroup" X="20" Y="55" Width="330" Height="120" Property="WixAppFolder" Hidden="yes">
                    <RadioButtonGroup Property="WixAppFolder">
                        <RadioButton Value="WixPerUserFolder" X="0" Y="0" Width="295" Height="16" Text="!(loc.InstallScopeDlgPerUser)" />
                        <RadioButton Value="WixPerMachineFolder" X="0" Y="60" Width="295" Height="16" Text="!(loc.InstallScopeDlgPerMachine)" />
                    </RadioButtonGroup>
                    <Condition Action="show">Privileged AND (!(wix.WixUISupportPerUser) AND !(wix.WixUISupportPerMachine))</Condition>
                </Control>
                <Control Id="PerUserDescription" Type="Text" X="33" Y="70" Width="300" Height="36" Hidden="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.InstallScopeDlgPerUserDescription)">
                    <Condition Action="show">!(wix.WixUISupportPerUser)</Condition>
                </Control>
                <Control Id="NoPerUserDescription" Type="Text" X="33" Y="70" Width="300" Height="36" Hidden="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.InstallScopeDlgNoPerUserDescription)">
                    <Condition Action="show">NOT !(wix.WixUISupportPerUser)</Condition>
                </Control>
                <Control Id="PerMachineDescription" Type="Text" X="33" Y="131" Width="300" Height="36" Hidden="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.InstallScopeDlgPerMachineDescription)">
                    <Condition Action="show">Privileged</Condition>
                </Control>
                <Control Id="DesktopShortcutCheckBox" Type="CheckBox" X="20" Y="160" Width="290" Height="17" Property="INSTALLDESKTOPSHORTCUT" CheckBoxValue="1" Text="Create a shortcut on the desktop." />

                <Control Id="Back" Type="PushButton" X="180" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Text="!(loc.WixUIBack)" />
                <Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUINext)" />
                <Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Cancel="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUICancel)">
                    <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CancelDlg">1</Publish>
                </Control>
            </Dialog>
        </UI>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are still referencing the original WixUI_Advanced UI.

```
<UI Id="WixUI_AdvancedCrypto">
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_Advanced" />
    <DialogRef Id="InstallScopeDlgDsktp" />
```

This pulls in the InstallScopeDlg and will be causing your conflict. Take a copy of the WixUI_Advanced wxs from the wix sources and include in your project renaming it so that it doesn't conflict and then modify it to use your new InstallScopeDlgDsktop.

Comment: I was trying to avoid that as I had problems getting that working (I think this was because WixUI_Advanced is not just one <Fragment> with a <UI> element, like WixUI_InstallDir and the others are, but also has a bunch of <CustomAction> elements etc), and I saw an example that avoided duplicating the whole of WixUI_Mondo, and instead just overrode some <Publish> elements.  I thought the same would work for WixUI_Advanced - but *many* thanks for explaining that referencing WixUI_Advanced would then pull in the original InstallScopeDlg, regardless of whether I tried to override any calls to it.

Comment: So I went back to the method you suggested and managed to resolve the issues with the <Customaction> elements by renaming all the Ids in my specific version, and it worked! So happy now. Cheers heaps!

Comment: No probs!! Yeah this kind of thing threw me quite a bit. Always remember that if you reference one thing in a fragment, everything is included from that fragment.